# How can I enter key passphrase only once instead of thrice?

Tags: ssh, passphrase

I have a passphrase protected key file to access server. I have to enter passphrase thrice every time I open my computer. Once for pagent (putty, winscp, ...). Once for bash (git, ...). And once for powershell script that backs up my mysql database. How can I enter it only once and use it for all three functions?

Comment: They all user different agents. There are some bridges that can connect them, like https://github.com/ndbeals/winssh-pageant or https://github.com/benpye/wsl-ssh-pageant