# How to use Putty with Windows openssh-agent?

Tags: windows, windows-10, putty, openssh, ssh-agent

I've upgraded my Windows OpenSSH to the latest version (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/) in order to get it accept my RSA key.

Now i can add my key e.g. with `ssh-add private.key` and see it listed in `ssh-add -l`. I can also use `ssh me@sshenabledserver.local` to connect to a Linux host from a Windows shell without a password prompt.

But i cannot figure out how to use it with Putty. I enabled `Allow agent forwarding` in the default settings, but when i connect to the same host as above, i get an password prompt :-(

I tested this with Pageant in a similar way and it worked, but i really like to have it without Pageant, using the native Windows Agent. Of course the service is running inside Windows and set to automatically start with the machine.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1582016/213663

Comment: That's not my issue. I use a key without a passphrase.

Comment: Then sorry, i don't get how the "answer" given there could help me out. Please explain in detail.

Comment: The answer is that PuTTY cannot talk to  OpenSSH agent. There are tools (mentioned in my comment to the linked question) that can bridge the PuTTY to OpenSSH agent. But I've never used any of them.

Comment: Ok, that was my "missing link". So Putty is only able to use Pageant, which on the other hand other tools cannot use. So i might need to look at an alternative to Putty...

Comment: You could also use openssh-client `ssh` command from Windows then, they play together nicely. Looks good in the new Windows Terminal (integrated in Win11 anyway).